# Syntax highlighting in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, syntax, uitextfield, text-coloring

We all know how Xcode changes the colors of certain parts of our code to tell us what kind of object it is right?  (Ex.  Blue for numbers, green for comments, etc.)

I was wondering how this was accomplished. I want to do this in a UITextView, but I will make my own classes if I have to. Are there any useful threads or tutorials around that have to do with this?

Comment: Please, please don't advertise your own apps in a question again.

Comment: @Tom Irving: Haha sorry.  =)  Though I would give it a shot, didn't know it made people like you so mad.

Comment: It's not a question of being mad, an assumption I can't work out how you've got to, it's a question of following the rules of the website.

Comment: @Tom Irving: Whatever man, maybe you should tell me that I'm not supposed to do that instead of making me seem like I break the rules a lot.

Comment: Please don't exacerbate this. I made it clear in my first comment, all you had to do was apologize. There is no need for the attitude.

Comment: @Tom Irving: Can I advertise random people's apps, just not mine?  Please specify now before I get yelled at again.  Thanks for being "that guy."

Comment: This is a website for programming related questions, not advertising. No one is yelling, by the way.

Comment: @Tom Irving: Hmmmmmm... should have told me that you could not advertise other people's apps.  I almost did it.  My rational mind said no, lucky for you.     Haha, I'm just pullin' your leg. =)  Sorry about the advertisements. (:<)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITextView doesn't accept more than one style of text, so syntax coloring isn't possible with the control.

You'll have to do you own displaying and editing with the Core Text framework and the UITextInput protocol.

As for the actual coloring, there are some open source code editors that it might be worth taking a look at, for example [Fragaria](https://github.com/mugginsoft/Fragaria).

Though it is a Cocoa project, not Cocoa Touch, it should still be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the [Core Text API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html).

If you want to go beyond the SDK, Oliver Drobnik wrote some articles and code about extending NSAttributedString. Check http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/ and https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML